# Moment returns wrong datetime

Tags: reactjs, momentjs

I am using React as a front-end framework, python as a back-end language.

Python returns UTC datetime to React. Somehow, react+moment shows wrong local datetime (Berlin timezone). May I know, what to fix this issue ?

**Case 1 is correct**, ***but case 2 is wrong***

**Case 1:**

*Python returns to React:* "2019-10-02T22:00:00Z"

*React+Moment returns:* Thu Oct 03 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time) {}

```
moment('2019-10-02T22:00:00Z').toDate()

Thu Oct 03 2019 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
```

**Case 2:**

*Python returns to React:* "2019-10-30T22:00:00Z"

*React+Moment returns:* Wed Oct 30 2019 23:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time) {}

```
 moment('2019-10-30T22:00:00Z').toDate()

 Wed Oct 30 2019 23:00:00 GMT+0100 (Central European Standard Time)
```

Comment: Summer time ends on October 27, so it seems correct.

Comment: @Dyo Oops..You are right. May In know, How to tackle this situation ? I mean, to display the correct datetime

Comment: "Correct datetime" depends on your app's needs, do you want to handle local datetimes or just use utc ?

Comment: @Dyo I want to handle local datetimes, because multiple users access the same logic in different locations

Comment: Your time will still be the same in utc, just make sure to always print it in local format to the end user.

Answer (score 2):

Python is using `utc` while moment.js is using an extra offset of `+1` or whatever (your local time). If you want moment.js to use `utc` too, do this:

```
const m = moment.utc('2019-10-30T22:00:00Z')
console.log(m.toDate())
```

Comment: Thank you..Does explicit UTC returns any trouble when multiple users in different locations tries to access the same logic

Comment: No trouble, they would all get the `utc` version of the time.